# How to filter an array of objects with array as one of the object parameters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I've got this object:

```
this.contacts = [
            {
                name: "",
                el: ["one", "two"]
            },
            {
                name: "",
                el: ["three", "four"]
            }]
```

How to filter the above so for example only the first object is returned when I search for "two"?

My try so far:

```
filterItems(searchTerm) {

    return this.contacts.filter((item) => {
        return item.el.filter((user) => {
            return user.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        })
    });

}
```

It doesn't return anything of course, why?

Comment: If you have another object with 'two' in it, should it return that object as well or should it stop after first successful match?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and take it as filter condition.

```js
function filterItems(user) {
    return this.contacts.filter(item => item.el
        .map(s => s.toLowerCase())
        .includes(user.toLowerCase()))
}

var contacts = [{ name: "", el: ["one", "two"] }, { name: "", el: ["thrEE", "four"] }];

console.log(filterItems('THREE'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the first `.filter` you should use [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var contacts = [{
    name: "",
    el: ["one", "two"]
  },
  {
    name: "",
    el: ["three", "four"]
  }
]

filterItems = function(searchTerm) {
  return contacts.filter((item) => {
    return item.el.some((user) => {
      return user.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    })
  });
}

console.log(filterItems("two"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to achieve a similar effect but by using loops you could use the following function:

```
function filterItems(search) {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.contacts.length; i++) {
        let obj = this.contacts[i];
        for(let j = 0; j < obj.el.length; j++) {
            if(obj.el[j] === search) return i;
        }
    }
}

console.log(filterItems("two")); // logs 0 (returns 0) 
console.log(filterItems("four")); // logs 1 (returns 1)
```

Essentially the first loop is used to loop through your contacts array. And then the second is used to loop through the array in the `el` property. Then upon each iteration of the `el` array, we can check if the array element we are currently on equals the passed through `search` value, thus returning `true` if it matches

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/knLbL9b5/ (Check console for outputs)